# Is it okay declare functions inside the build method?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been declaring functions inside the build method and now I am wondering whether this is a bad practice.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  void doRegister() async {
    ...
  }

  return Scaffold(
    ...
  );
}
```

Are there any problems with this approach and should I declare functions outside of the build method?

Comment: Better Use state management(bloc,getx,etc)

Comment: see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/build.html

Answer (score 2):

No, You should not declare a function in the build method, the build method may call several times and you shouldn't have logic in your build method. declare method outside of build method or use state management like bloc.

Comment: Any reference to back up this answer?

Answer (score 1):

It's bad practice because the method will call unnecessarily every time you build the widget. It will make your app performance slow .

Comment: Any reference on this (about the performance thing)? _the method will call unnecessarily every time_ what is being called, elaborate please?